# Error #2032: Stream Error. while calling webservices through an ssl connection

Tags: actionscript-3, web-services, apache-flex, ssl, air

I'm trying to access a webservice with an SSL connection from an AIR application, I can access the webservice and retrieve the data without SSL, but when I try and access it through it I end up getting the 2032 Stream Error. As if what I was attempting to access wasn't available (which in fact it is, since I can easilly access it through my browsers).

I am doing the following:

```
    private var server:String = "";
    private var contentType:String = "";
    private var method:String = "";
    private var connector:connectionTest = null;
    private var serverURL:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

    public function Connector(a2:String, a3:String, mainClass:connectionTest)
    {
        server = "url";
        contentType = a2;
        method = a3;
        connector = mainClass;
    }

    public function callService(callback:String, request:Object):void{
        var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest(server);
        var encoder2:JSONEncoder = new JSONEncoder(request);
        var requestedString:String = "0" + encoder2.getString();
        url.contentType = contentType;
        url.method = method;
        url.data = "callback=" + callback;
        url.data +="&request=" + encodeURI(requestedString);
        url.authenticate = true;
        serverURL.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, treatIO);
        serverURL.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadData);
        try{
            serverURL.load(url);
        }catch(e:ArgumentError){trace("ArgError: " + e.message);}
        catch(e:SecurityError){trace("SecError: " + e.message);}
    }
    private function treatIO(e:IOErrorEvent):void{
        trace(e.text);
    }

    private function loadData(e:Event):void{
        trace("loaded");
        connector.htmlObject.htmlText = serverURL.data as String;
        trace(serverURL.data);
    }
```

explanation: mainClass is an mxml file with just a button and an html object in it.

Note: I have done the recommended thing of adding to Flex the certificate.

Anyone out there that can assist with this?

**Edit:**
I also tried with the URLStream class and it still doesn't handle it, seems like I can't actually get a connection to the server...

Even tho I do connect to it in a browser or even SoapUI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We faced the same problem on some machines (Win7 64bit), unfortunatelly still not solved. Maybe this is relevant:

http://forums.adobe.com/message/4028647#4028647

Answer (score 0):

When I ran into this problem it was caused by my hosting company introducing an inconsistency between the name in the SSL certificate and the URL I was calling, when I replaced https://www.example.com/ with https://example.com/ everything started to work again.